# Samba 3.5 Shadow Copy for Windows 7

Tags: samba, snapshot, vss, dell-equallogic

Over the past several days I have been trying to get the shadow to work with samba but haven’t been successful. Can someone check below config and let me know if I am missing something? We are using Equallogic SAN and iSCSI LUNS to mount volumes.

I can cleanly access samba shares on Windows 7 clients but just not shadow copy. I have referred the official how-to but couldn’t get it to work. I see these messages in the logs.  Any help is deeply appreciated.

> [2012/10/31 12:20:53.549863,  0]
>   smbd/nttrans.c:2170(call_nt_transact_ioctl)
>   FSCTL_GET_SHADOW_COPY_DATA: connectpath /fs/test-01, failed.
>
> [2012/10/31 12:21:13.887198,  0]
>   modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:734(shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy2_data)
>   shadow:snapdir not found for /fs/test-01 in get_shadow_copy_data
>
> [2012/10/31 12:21:13.887265,  0]
>   smbd/nttrans.c:2170(call_nt_transact_ioctl)
>   FSCTL_GET_SHADOW_COPY_DATA: connectpath /fs/test-01, failed.

== Samba pkgs ==

- samba-3.5.10-116.el6_2.x86_64
- samba-common-3.5.10-116.el6_2.x86_64
- samba-winbind-clients-3.5.10-116.el6_2.x86_64
- samba-client-3.5.10-116.el6_2.x86_64

=== df –h ==
First is the iSCSI LUN and 2 others are snapshots.

```
/dev/mapper/eql-0-fs-test01   5.0G  2.3G  2.5G  48% /fs/test-01 
/dev/mapper/eql-2-0+fs-test01 5.0G  2.3G  2.5G  48% /fs/test-01/@GMT-2012.10.26-17.32.42/fs/test-01   (SNAPSHOT-1) 
/dev/mapper/eql-d-0+fs-test01 5.0G  2.3G  2.5G  48% /fs/test-01/@GMT-2012.10.31-11.52.42/fs/test-01   (SNAPSHOT- 2)
```

===/etc/samba/smb.conf ===

```
[global]
        workgroup = DOMAIN
        server string = Samba Server Version %v
        security = ads
        realm = DOMAIN.CORP
        encrypt passwords = yes
        guest account = nobody
        map to guest = bad uid
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log

        domain master = no
        local master = no
        preferred master = no
        os level = 0

        load printers = no
        show add printer wizard = no
        printable = no
        printcap name = /dev/null
        disable spoolss = yes

        follow symlinks = yes
        wide links = yes
        unix extensions = no

[test]
        comment = Test Directories
        path = /fs/test-01
        vfs objects = shadow_copy2
        #shadow_copy2: sort = desc
        #shadow: localtime = yes
        #shadow: snapdir = /fs/test-01/test
        #shadow: basedir = /fs/test-01
        guest ok = yes
        writeable = yes
        map archive = no
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 2770
        inherit owner = yes
        inherit permissions = yes
```

All feedback is welcome. Thanks!